# Cannot locate ViewBinding source code in Google repo

Tags: android, android-viewbinding, jetpack-compose-androidviewbinding

I'm looking to find out the source code of the view binding tool. There's probably some sort of processor or compiler plugin that consumes layout files and spits out those java source files.

Where can I find the code?
Looked a bit in Google's repo, couldn't locate it.